# openldap read/write performance

Tags: performance, openldap

I am using OpenLDAP slapd version 2.4.33 with the slapd configuration below. I am trying to run some tests with ldapadd and ldapsearch tools to measure its write and read performance but I am getting really poor performance results.

System: sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T2000 with 64 GB of memory.
Tried to add 1500 entried and it took 1 minute 19 seconds.

```
time ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=my-company,dc=com" -w mypassword -f /tmp/perf1500.ldif > /dev/null 2>&1
ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=my-company,dc=com" -w mypassword -f /tmp/perf200.ldif >    1.27s user 0.14s system 1% cpu 1:19.95 total
```

There is a similar configuration test results are give on http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/OpenLDAP_MDB_vs_HDB_performance#MDB_configuration . But I am not even close to that.

MDB configuration:

```
database  mdb
directory /home/myuser/var/openldap-data
suffix    "dc=my-company,dc=com"
rootdn    "cn=Manager,dc=my-company,dc=com"
rootpw    mypassword
index     objectClass   eq
index     myMSISDN     eq
maxsize   10737418240
envflags writemap,nometasync
```

The problem is system is not even being busy but the openldap performance is very poor. How a configuration may provide a better performance? Is there something that is so obvious that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Is the database on a local disk?

Comment: Yes. It is located on the same server, on the local disk.